# multi_index in eos with AddressBook example

Tags: smart-contract, eosio.cdt

I building AddressBook by link https://developers.eos.io/eosio-home/docs/data-persistence,

> Dependencies:
>   EOSIO.CDT (Contract Development Toolkit)
>   Version : 1.3.1

Here is my code:

```
#include <eosiolib/eosio.hpp>
#include <eosiolib/action.hpp>
#include <eosiolib/contract.hpp>
#include <eosiolib/print.hpp>
#include <string>

using std::string;
using namespace eosio;

CONTRACT addressbook : public eosio::contract {
public:
  using contract::contract;
  ACTION hi( name user ) {
        require_auth(user);
      print( "Hello, ", name{user} );
  }
 private:
  TABLE person {
      uint64_t account_name;
      string first_name;
      string last_name;
      string street;
      string city;
      string state;
      uint32_t zip = 0;

      uint64_t primary_key() const { return account_name; }
      uint64_t by_zip() const { return zip; }
  };
 typedef eosio::multi_index<N(people), person> address_index;
};

EOSIO_DISPATCH( addressbook, (hi) )
```

Error message:

```
addressbook.cpp:55:35: error: use of undeclared identifier 'people'
 typedef eosio::multi_index<N(people), person> address_index;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
typedef eosio::multi_index<"people"_n, test::person> address_index;
```

Comment: thank you very much, build completed.  <3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3

Comment: They have changed some syntaxes in eosio.cdt which is different than eosiocpp so thats why you have faced this issue.

Comment: I also know that problem, but because of foreign language, and new programming with c language, eos blockchain is hard to reach.
Now, there is another error, can you help me? Thank you
https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/2753/no-matching-constructor-for-initialization-addressbook-example