# No matching constructor for initialization AddressBook example

Tags: smart-contract, eosio.cdt

> Dependencies:
>   EOSIO.CDT (Contract Development Toolkit) Version : 1.3.1

My code:

```
#include <eosiolib/eosio.hpp>
#include <eosiolib/print.hpp>

using namespace eosio;

CONTRACT addressbook : public eosio::contract {

 public:
    using contract::contract;

    addressbook(name self): contract(self) {}

   [[eosio::action]]
   void upsert(name user, std::string first_name, std::string 
   last_name, std::string street, std::string city, std::string state) 
   {
       require_auth( user );
       address_index addresses(_self, _self);
       auto iterator = addresses.find( user );
       if( iterator == addresses.end() )
       {
           addresses.emplace(user, [&]( auto& row ) {
           row.key = user;
           row.first_name = first_name;
           row.last_name = last_name;
           row.street = street;
           row.city = city;
           row.state = state;
        });
      }
    else 
    {
       std::string changes;
       addresses.modify(iterator, user, [&]( auto& row ) {
       row.key = user;
       row.first_name = first_name;
       row.last_name = last_name;
       row.street = street;
       row.city = city;
       row.state = state;
     });
   }
 }

[[eosio::action]]
void erase(name user){
   // require_auth(user);
    address_index addresses(_self, _self);
    auto iterator = addresses.find( user );
    eosio_assert(iterator != addresses.end(), "Record does not 
        exist");
    addresses.erase(iterator);
}

 private:
 struct [[eosio::table]] person {
       name key;
       std::string first_name;
       std::string last_name;
       std::string street;
       std::string city;
       std::string state;
       uint64_t primary_key() const { return key; }
  };
   typedef eosio::multi_index<"people"_n, person> address_index;

  };

EOSIO_ABI( addressbook, (upsert)(erase) )
```

Error message:

```
    ./addressbook.cpp:12:30: error: no matching constructor for 
     initialization of 'eosio::contract'
     addressbook(name self) : contract(self) {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank Mr.Y. I fixed, and made action insert,update,remove,search... is ok.
Thanks for your instructions, I will look at eosio code more thoroughly.
1. remove line:

```
addressbook(name self) : contract(self) {}
```

2. change line :

```
address_index addresses(_self, _self);
```

to :

```
address_index addresses(_self, _self.value);
```

3. change line :

```
auto iterator = addresses.find( user );
```

to :

```
unit64 user_index=user.value;
auto iterator = addresses.find( user_index );
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but i think you need to remove this

```
addressbook(name self) : contract(self) {}
```

because they are not supporting this constructor anymore.
 Have a look at new constructor

```
contract( name receiver, name code, datastream<const char*> ds ):_self(receiver),_code(code),_ds(ds) {}
```

You can use in your code like

```
addressbook(name self) : contract(_self,_code,_ds){}
```

Comment: thank you.
removed but :
line code :  address_index addresses(_self, _self); to error.

Comment: i have edited my answer try this